# Remove/hide port number from URL address

Tags: security, url, tomcat, port

It's not as simple as it looks.

I've been given the task to add a third tomcat to a server that already has two Tomcats working.

Problem is, this third Tomcat needs to be secure, and the port needs to be hidden. Since Tomcat 1 is currently using port 433 (secure) and Tomcat 2 is using port 80, my third tomcat is out of widely accepted non-showing ports.

How can I hide the port? Proxies? Virtual Hosts? I NEED it to be separated from the other two. Any suggestion is highly welcomed.

Comment: You are likely to get a better answer at serverfault.com.

Answer (score 2):

If you bind your new tomcat to a different domain name and IP, you can still use ports 80 and/or 443.

Answer (score 1):

That is how the browsers work. They assume port 80 for http unless you specify a different port. If you specify different port, then the port number must be specified in the url.